# BizTalk WCF-CUSTOM Sqlbinding generates a type conversion error from string to byte[]

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am migrating a BizTalk 2010 solution to BizTalk 2016. Everything has been largely copied & pasted so no changes there (and the 2010 version works) but when I send a message to a WCF-CUSTOM port - sqlbinding to stored procedures - it stops and logs a type conversion error from string to byte[].

I have tried putting the same message through the 2010 deployment and that works fine but not the 2016. I have tried creating another simple orchestration with the schema generated from the stored procedure and it also produces the error (see below).

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "WcfSendPort_SqlAdapterBinding_TypedProcedures_dbo_Custom" with URL "mssql://*****". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[]. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'.
>      at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)".

The message it should be sending is

[image: store proc message]

Here is the stored proc

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[***]
    (
        @BatchId BIGINT OUTPUT,
        @BatchGuid VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
        @Contract VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
        @Initiating***Id BIGINT = NULL,
        @LinesExpected INT = NULL,
        @LinesProcessed INT = NULL,
        @SourceSystemMessageId VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
        @SourceSystemName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
        @CreatedBy NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
        @RowId  TIMESTAMP  = 0x00000000000007D9 OUTPUT 
    )
    AS

        SET NOCOUNT ON


        if @BatchGuid  is NULL
        set @BatchGuid = ''
        if @Contract  is NULL
        set @Contract  = ''
        if @Initiating***Id is NULL
        set @Initiating***Id = 0
        if @LinesExpected  is NULL
        set @LinesExpected  = 0
        if @LinesProcessed is NULL
        set @LinesProcessed = 0
        if @SourceSystemMessageId  is  NULL
        set @SourceSystemMessageId  = ''
        if @SourceSystemName is NULL
        set  @SourceSystemName  = ''
        if @CreatedBy is NULL
        set @CreatedBy  = ''



        INSERT INTO dbo.[***]
        (
            [BatchGuid],
            [Contract],
            [Initiating***Id],
            [LinesExpected],
            [LinesProcessed],
            [SourceSystemMessageId],
            [SourceSystemName],
            [CreatedBy],
            [CreatedDate]
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @BatchGuid,
            @Contract,
            @Initiating***Id,
            @LinesExpected,
            @LinesProcessed,
            @SourceSystemMessageId,
            @SourceSystemName,
            @CreatedBy,
            getdate()

        )

        SELECT @BatchId = Scope_Identity()

        SELECT @RowId = RowId FROM [***]
        WHERE  [BatchId] = @BatchId

        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        RETURN

GO
```

Please note the *** are just covering up sensitive information

Comment: have you tried changing the send pipeline to passthrough?

Comment: @Jason Hoyle , did you enable EnableBizTalkCompatibilityMode (also during schema generation) ?

Comment: @metal Hi, yes I tried that but it produces the same error

Comment: @r3verse Yes, that's is set for both

Comment: What is the DbType of the parameter in question?

Comment: @Johns-305 Just string or Ints. I'll add a screenshot of the message to the post

Comment: Can you add the definition of the Stored Procedure you are calling?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Hi I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was due to the null value in rowId parameter. It would seem that BizTalk 10 handled null values differently.

Comment: Technically, it's the new XslTransform class from NetFx that causes this. :)